# Simple way of using netty with ssl certificate?

Tags: java, ssl, netty, syslog

I'm trying to use netty to write to a syslog server using SSL, and I think I've got my head round the netty part, I seem to just need to add this line:  `channel.pipeline().addLast("ssl", sslCtx.newHandler(channel.alloc(), host, 5000))`.

Full code:

```
bootstrap.channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
    .option(ChannelOption.SO_KEEPALIVE, true)
    .handler(new TcpSyslogEventEncoder());

try {
  ChannelFuture future = bootstrap.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, 5000));
  channel = future.syncUninterruptibly().channel();
  channel.pipeline().addLast("ssl", sslCtx.newHandler(channel.alloc(), host, 5000));
}
catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("Unable to connect to host.  Cause is " + e.toString());
}
```

My problem is getting the SslContext (sslCtx) object setup.  I already have the certificate I want to use (it's a .crt file containing text like:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIDBjCCAe4CCQCmD....gM8vZVmYXULV8A==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I see to have to jump through loads of hoops in java to do this.  There must be a simpler way to use netty with SSL surely?  My code for setting up the sslCtx is:

```
EventLoopGroup group = null;
Bootstrap bootstrap = null;
Channel channel = null;
boolean initialized = false;
boolean connected = false;
java.io.FileInputStream fis = null;


// find out if keystore already exists
KeyStore ks = null;
try {
  ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
} catch (KeyStoreException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
// get user password and file input stream
char[] password = {'p','a','s','s','w','o','r','d'};


try {
  fis = new java.io.FileInputStream("newKeyStoreNamep12");
  ks.load(fis, password);
} catch (CertificateException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  if (fis != null) {
    fis.close();
  }
}


FileInputStream certFile = new FileInputStream("server.crt");
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(certFile);

CertificateFactory cf = null;
try {
  cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
} catch (CertificateException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

Certificate cert = null;


while (bis.available() > 0) {
  try {
    cert = cf.generateCertificate(bis);
  } catch (CertificateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  System.out.println("cert is: " + cert.toString());
}

ks.setCertificateEntry("myalias", cert);


KeyManagerFactory kmf;
kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("IbmX509");
kmf.init(ks, password);



group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
bootstrap = new Bootstrap();
bootstrap.group(group);
initialized = true;
connected = false;


SslContextBuilder ctxBuilder =     SslContextBuilder.forClient().keyManager(kmf);
SslContext sslCtx = ctxBuilder.build();
```

Answer (score 7):

Don't know what version you use, but in 4.0.30 you can setup ssl context like this:

```
SslContext sslCtx = SslContextBuilder.forServer(new File(certPath), new File(keyPath), null).build();
```

And after that add to pipeline:

```
pipeline.addLast(sslCtx.newHandler(channel .alloc()));
```

Comment: many thanks, I've narrowed down the scope of this a bit, and got a specific exception - will post a new question on it.